# Change the background of a TabItem header to a darker hue when selected

Tags: wpf

I have a TabControl with several TabItems. These TabItems define their own Background color which differs between tabs. I then have a Style that sets other display properties of the header, primarily its border, which I apply via the TabControl's ItemContainerStyle property.

What I want to do is use each TabItem's Background color as the background of the header, then when that TabItem is selected, display the tab using a darker hue of the color.

I'm currently trying to use a databinding with an IValueConverter that takes the SolidColorBrush specified as the Background of the TabItem and returns another Brush with the darker color, but no matter what I try to specify as the binding path or source I cannot access the property of the object to which the style is being applied; the converter is either given a null value, the name of the property I want to use as a string, or is not executed at all.

Comment: Any reason why you are trying to implicitly get the tab item's background color as opposed to explicity setting the tab items two background colors?

Comment: Show your XAML. No reason why this won't work.